# Swift - Charts Framework - How to Hide/Show line plots?

Tags: swift, plot, frameworks, hide, ios-charts

I am using the Charts framework for Swift. I am graphing multiple data sets into a scatter plot, such that there are multiple lines/graphs within one single chart view.

I would like to be able to dynamically show/hide any combination of these plots, but don't know the API command to do so (or if it exists).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want show any data set, check out `dataSet.visible` property.